# Consolidate multiple values into a cell in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to aggregate some data from our database into a cohesive table with the below query. The issue is that users can belong to more than one group, so any time that happens, the user data is duplicated on a new row with everything the same aside from the group column.  I'd like to consolidate those groups into a single, comma-separated value.  I've tried a few different things like STRING_AGG and COALESCE, but the data is linked across so many different tables and data types that I'm having issues getting that to work.

Query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, 
--POSITION
JSON_VALUE(p.NameJson,'$[0].Text') AS Position, 
--DEPARTMENT
JSON_VALUE(d.NameJson,'$[0].Text') AS Department, 
--USER GROUPS
JSON_VALUE(ug.NameJson, '$[0].Text') AS Groups,
--ROLES
JSON_VALUE(sr.TitleJson, '$[0].Text') AS Roles
    FROM AspNetUsers a
    LEFT JOIN Positions p 
    ON a.PositionId = p.Id
    LEFT JOIN Departments d
    ON a.DepartmentId = d.Id
    LEFT JOIN UserRoles ur
    ON a.Id = ur.UserId
    LEFT JOIN UserGroupUsers ugu
    ON a.Id = ugu.User_Id
    LEFT JOIN UserGroups ug
    ON ugu.UserGroup_Id = ug.Id
    LEFT JOIN SecurityRoles sr
    ON ur.RoleId = sr.Id

ORDER BY LastName desc
```

EDIT:
Here's the actual data, redacted a bit.

| firstName | lastName | email | position | department | groups | roles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Last | Email | City Clerk | City Clerk | City Clerk | Administrator |
| First | Last | Email | City Clerk | City Clerk | DH_City Clerk | Administrator |
| First | Last | Email | City Clerk | City Clerk | City Clerk Group | Administrator |

The goal here is to return one row that reads:

| firstName | lastName | email | position | department | groups | roles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Last | Email | City Clerk | City Clerk | City Clerk, DH_City Clerk, City Clerk Group | Administrator |

Comment: Sample data (in a consumable format) and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: choose  one of this https://www.sqlfeathers.com/2018/07/using-stuff-and-stringagg-in-sql-server.html